# Plotting TP line

Tags: pine-script

This is the code I've tried thus far:

```
longTP = longentry and (open + 0.0023)
shortTP = shortentry and (open -0.0023)

plot(longTP or shortTP,"TP",color.green,1)
```

I'd like to make it so the TP line only plots for the most recent signal, ie. shortentry/longentry. Any input is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your longTP is a boolean, the plot function needs a float value to plot. Assuming you want your longTP to be the opening price + .00023 you could do something like this

```
var longTP = 0.0
if longentry
    longTP := open + .0023
```